# Removing Repeated Objects - During or After Creation?

Tags: sql, ruby, object

I'll try not to be abstract here:

I am querying a large number of items from an external database and creating respective objects in my own SQL databases.

Now, in my queries, there are definitely repeats (unavoidable)...so, from a runtime standpoint, would it be faster to *create the objects* then delete the repeats OR to do this before actually creating the objects?

It seems like the SQL `WHERE` queries before creating the object take a long time.

I'm working in Ruby, so here is an example of the latter:

```
objects_hash.map { |d| Object.where(:attr1 => d["attr1"], :attr2 => d["attr2"]).exists? ? false : Object.create(:attr1 => d["attr1"], :attr2 => d["attr2"]) }
```

Comment: Can you determine identical objects from a single DB column? Then your problem could be solved by forcing this column to be unique.

Comment: Uh... there is nothing like "unavoidable repeats". Any repeating group can be singularized by selection and projection operations. It's so true that some SQL versions have the DISTINCT clause. A different problem is doing that in "short" time.

Comment: @padde Unfortunately - need two columns to determine uniqueness.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri, to be clearer - I'm querying Facebook for every friends likes...but, there are repeats among friends.